# How to assign variable to insert into a Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables.

1. NewTransaction_tb
2. OldTransaction_tb

I want to move the records from old to new table including date. But the `OldTransaction_tb` it doesn't have the `Date` column.

This is what I am trying.

For example

```
DECLARE @VarDate Datetime = CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),102)

INSERT INTO HQMatajer.dbo.NewTransaction_tb
    SELECT
        Name, class, Qualification, @VarDate  //this @VarDate is not in OldTransaction_tb
    FROM 
        HQMatajer.dbo.OldTransaction_tb
```

What is the solution for this scenario? Thanks,

Comment: what is the result of your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to declare a variable for doing this, you can directly convert the string from the old table and insert to the new one.

```
INSERT into HQMatajer.dbo.NewTransaction_tb
SELECT Name,class,Qualification,CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),102)
FROM HQMatajer.dbo.OldTransaction_tb
```

Comment: Thanks, its second time you are answering me.

Comment: True, the direct approach *does*  work. However, there can be a difference, when it comes to long tables. The original approach (there should have been a separate `SET` command after the `DECLARE`) would result in *identical*  values for all rows, whereas in your solution you will have *slight time differences* between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly Date in select column

```
SELECT
Name,class,Qualification,CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),102)
```

Comment: oh my god!... for this simple work I am thinking outside of box. Thanks bro

Comment: Happy to Help! :)

Answer (score 1):

See, the answer to this can be what you wrote or what others suggested. 
The question is what you want in your result set. 
For example, if you are processing a data set all at once, say entire of OldTransaction table, and you want that all the rows being transferred to NewTransaction should have the same DateTime, then it is preferred to do it by first declaring a variable and then calling it.

This is better than using the function in a SELECT clause because the function is then called once for every row. So if you have a billion rows in OldTransaction table then the function will be called a billion times and you will have a small speed impact.

But if your require all rows to have the exact date time of insertion, in case your insert takes a prolonged time over an hour or so, then there is no choice but to use the function within the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT
Name, Class, Qualification, CONVERT(Datetime, GETDATE(), 102)
FROM HQMatajer.dbo.OldTransaction_tb
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

if table does not yet exist then use :

```
Select * 
Into NewTransaction_tb 
From 
    (select 
         * ,CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 102) as Date 
     from 
         OldTransaction_tb) a
```

OR 
if table already exists, then use :

```
insert into NewTransaction_tb
    select 
        *, CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 102) as Date  
    from 
        OldTransaction_tb
```

Comment: It would be **important** to mention which approach works in what situation. The `SELECT .. INTO ....` **only** works if the target table **does not yet exist** - if it already exists, then you **must use** approach #2 ....